# ASP.NET Core OnPost() issue with loading data

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass an `IEnumerable` to my `OnPost()` method, but everything I've tried so far just results in it being null or having a `Count` of 0. In the `OnGet()`, I throw all the needed data into it and I can print it out on the webpage just fine. Here is the code I have:

EditLocations.cshtml:

```asp
@page "{assessmentId}"
@model CustomerPageTest.Pages.View.EditLocationsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditLocations";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-offset-4 justify-content-center">
    <h1 style="color:yellowgreen">Edit Locations</h1>
</div>
<br /><br />

      <form method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark text-light" />
          </div>
      </form>

      
<br />
<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search ID, Host, Datacenter, Cluster, Location Name, City, State, or Bandwidth" class="form-control" asp-for="SearchTerm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="text-light" style="border-top: hidden !important">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Host</td>
            <td>Datacenter</td>
            <td>Cluster</td>
            <td>Location Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>State</td>
            <td>Bandwidth</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var location in Model.LocationViews)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="@location.isChecked" name="@location.isChecked" /></td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.vHost_id
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.vHost_id" name="@location.vHost_id" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.Host
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.Host" name="@location.Host" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.Datacenter
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.Datacenter" name="@location.Datacenter" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.Cluster
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.Cluster" name="@location.Cluster" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.name
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.name" name="@location.name" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.city
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.city" name="@location.city" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.state
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.state" name="@location.state" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @location.bandwidth
                    <input type="hidden" id="@location.bandwidth" name="@location.bandwidth" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--<a class="btn btn-dark"
                    asp-page="/View/EditAssessment" asp-route-assessmentId="">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                    </a>-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</form>
```

EditLocations.cshtml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using KelderModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CustomerPageTest.Pages.View
{
    public class EditLocationsModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; } //Search term for search bar

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public IEnumerable<LocationView> LocationViews { get; set; }

        public int assessment_id { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(int assessmentId)
        {
            assessment_id = assessmentId;
            LocationViews = GetLocationViewsByAssessment(assessmentId);
            bool intOrString = false; //If false, its a string, if true, its an int
            try
            {
                int convertToInt = Int32.Parse(SearchTerm);
                intOrString = true;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            if (intOrString)
            { //Whole if statement is for the search bar, enables searching data in any column
                if (!IsNullOrEmpty(GetLocationById(Convert.ToInt32(SearchTerm))))
                    LocationViews = GetLocationById(Convert.ToInt32(SearchTerm));
                else if (!IsNullOrEmpty(GetLocationByBandwidth(Convert.ToInt32(SearchTerm))))
                    LocationViews = GetLocationByBandwidth(Convert.ToInt32(SearchTerm));
            }
            else
            {
                if (!IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLocationByHost(SearchTerm)))
                    LocationViews = SearchLocationByHost(SearchTerm);
                else if (!IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLocationByDatacenter(SearchTerm)))
                    LocationViews = SearchLocationByDatacenter(SearchTerm);
                else if (!IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLocationByCluster(SearchTerm)))
                    LocationViews = SearchLocationByCluster(SearchTerm);
                else if (!IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLocationByLocationName(SearchTerm)))
                    LocationViews = SearchLocationByLocationName(SearchTerm);
                else if (!IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLocationByCity(SearchTerm)))
                    LocationViews = SearchLocationByCity(SearchTerm);
                else if (!IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLocationByState(SearchTerm)))
                    LocationViews = SearchLocationByState(SearchTerm);
            }
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            foreach(var location in LocationViews)
            {
                location.isChecked = true;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> GetLocationViewsByAssessment(int assessmentID) //Creates a list of locations based off of the locations in the database and assessment_id given
        {
            List<LocationView> returnList = new List<LocationView>();
            using (var context = new DataWarehouseContext())
            {
                List<int> vHostIDs = context.RvtoolsVHost //Gets list of vHostIDs mainly as a counter for the rows corresponding to the assessment_id
                    .Where(a => a.AssessmentId == assessment_id)
                    .Select(b => b.VHostId)
                    .ToList();

                foreach(int host in vHostIDs)
                {
                    LocationView temp = new LocationView();
                    temp.isChecked = false;
                    temp.assessment_id = assessmentID;
                    temp.vHost_id = host;

                    temp.location_id = context.Location //Returns LocationID from Location database table
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.LocationId)
                        .SingleOrDefault();

                    temp.name = context.Location //Returns Location Name from Location database table
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.Name)
                        .SingleOrDefault();

                    temp.city = context.Location //Returns City from Location database table
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.City)
                        .SingleOrDefault();

                    temp.state = context.Location //Returns State from Location database table
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.State)
                        .SingleOrDefault();

                    temp.bandwidth = context.Location //Returns City from Location database table
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.Bandwidth)
                        .SingleOrDefault();

                    temp.Host = context.RvtoolsVHost //returns Host Name from Host table using the vHostID that points at it
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.Name)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    temp.Datacenter = context.RvtoolsVHost //returns Cluster Name from Cluster table using the vHostID that points at it
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.Datacenter.Name)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    temp.Cluster = context.RvtoolsVHost //returns Cluster Name from Cluster table using the vHostID that points at it
                        .Where(a => a.VHostId == host)
                        .Select(b => b.VCluster.Name)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    returnList.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            return returnList;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> GetLocationById(int id) //Should only return a single location since ID is specific
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.ToString()) || c.location_id.ToString().Equals(id.ToString())
                   orderby c.bandwidth
                   select c;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> GetLocationByBandwidth(int id) //Can return many locations
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.ToString()) || c.bandwidth.ToString().StartsWith(id.ToString())
                   orderby c.bandwidth
                   select c;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> SearchLocationByHost(string name = null) //Can return many locations
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || c.Host.StartsWith(name)
                   orderby c.Host
                   select c;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> SearchLocationByDatacenter(string name = null) //Can return many locations
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || c.Datacenter.StartsWith(name)
                   orderby c.Datacenter
                   select c;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> SearchLocationByCluster(string name = null) //Can return many locations
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || c.Cluster.StartsWith(name)
                   orderby c.Cluster
                   select c;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> SearchLocationByLocationName(string name = null) //Can return many locations
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || c.name.StartsWith(name)
                   orderby c.name
                   select c;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> SearchLocationByCity(string name = null) //Can return many locations
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || c.city.StartsWith(name)
                   orderby c.city
                   select c;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LocationView> SearchLocationByState(string name = null) //Can return many locations
        {
            return from c in LocationViews
                   where string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || c.state.StartsWith(name)
                   orderby c.state
                   select c;
        }



        public bool IsNullOrEmpty<LocationView>(IEnumerable<LocationView> enumerable)
        {
            return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any();
        }

    }
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: replace ment of for loop in GetLocationViewsByAssessment function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,I find in your form,the submit button and the table is not in the same form so that when click the button the data of table will not be passed.And then the model binding is not correct,you can use `name="LocationViews[@i].xxx"` to bind data.Here is a demo worked:
cshtml:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 justify-content-center">
    <h1 style="color:yellowgreen">Edit Locations</h1>
</div>
<br />
<br />



<br />


<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="text-light" style="border-top: hidden !important">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Host</td>
            <td>Datacenter</td>
            <td>Cluster</td>
            <td>Location Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>State</td>
            <td>Bandwidth</td>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.LocationViews.Count(); i++) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).isChecked" name="LocationViews[@i].isChecked" /></td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).vHost_id
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).vHost_id" name="LocationViews[@i].vHost_id" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).Host
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).Host" name="LocationViews[@i].Host" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).Datacenter
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).Datacenter" name="LocationViews[@i].Datacenter" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).Cluster
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).Cluster" name="LocationViews[@i].Cluster" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).name
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).name" name="LocationViews[@i].name" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).city
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).city" name="LocationViews[@i].city" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).state
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).state" name="LocationViews[@i].state" />
                </td>
                <td class="text text-light">
                    @Model.LocationViews.ElementAt(i).bandwidth
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="LocationViews.ElementAt(i).bandwidth" name="LocationViews[@i].bandwidth" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--<a class="btn btn-dark"
                    asp-page="/View/EditAssessment" asp-route-assessmentId="">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                    </a>-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark text-light" />
</form>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class EditLocationsModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public IEnumerable<LocationView> LocationViews { get; set; }
        public ActionResult OnGet()
        {
            List < LocationView > list = new List<LocationView>();
            LocationView l1 = new LocationView { isChecked = false, vHost_id = 1, city = "city1", Host = "h1", Cluster = "c1", Datacenter = "d1", name = "location1", state = "state1", bandwidth = "b1" };
            LocationView l2 = new LocationView { isChecked = true, vHost_id = 2, city = "city2", Host = "h2", Cluster = "c2", Datacenter = "d2", name = "location2", state = "state2", bandwidth = "b2" };
            list.Add(l1);
            list.Add(l2);
            LocationViews = list;
            return Page();

        }
        public void OnPost() {
          
        }
    }
```

Result：
[image]

Comment: Thanks @YiyiYou! Out of all the information I could find through my other internet searches this was the best solution and only working one for me!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lvs = from ld in context.Location
        join h in context.HostTable on h.hostId equals ld.VHostId
        join c in context.ClusterTable on c.hostId equals ld.VHostId
        
        where vHostIDs.Contains(ld.VHostId)
        select new LocationView {
            isChecked = false,
            assessment_id = assessmentID,
            location_id = ld.LocationId,
            name = ld.Name,
            city = ld.City,
            state = ld.State,
            bandwidth = ld.Bandwidth,
            host = h.Name,
            Datacenter = c.Datacenter.Name,
            Cluster = c.VCluster.Name
            
        }
```

Instead of loop use Linq

Comment: Are you saying to use this in the OnPost? I would think the solution to this would be within the HTML portion of the page where I can pass the data through there, I'm just not sure how to do that.